# CoreLocation thread crash Crashed: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x16fcb870.events

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ibeacon

I'm getting this crash in Apple's CoreLocation thread in our production app. I am not able to reproduce it in my testing also its hard to figure out as its inside CoreLocation. At the moment its happening with few percentage of population but I can see its getting bigger.

```
   Crashed: com.apple.CoreLocation.ConnectionClient.0x16fcb870.events
0  CoreLocation                   0x2aa2db54 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 53675
1  CoreLocation                   0x2aa2dc7b CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 53970
2  CoreLocation                   0x2aa2de03 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 54362
3  CoreLocation                   0x2aa2dcfb CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 54098
4  CoreLocation                   0x2aa30f59 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 66992
5  CoreLocation                   0x2aa31089 CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 67296
6  CoreFoundation                 0x24954699 <redacted> + 16
7  CoreFoundation                 0x2493f698 <redacted> + 120
8  CoreFoundation                 0x24948575 CFDictionaryApplyFunction + 172
9  CoreLocation                   0x2aa3036d CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 63940
10 CoreLocation                   0x2aa2edaf CLClientCreateIso6709Notation + 58374
11 libxpc.dylib                   0x247816e5 <redacted> + 40
12 libxpc.dylib                   0x24784413 <redacted> + 122
13 libxpc.dylib                   0x2478436d <redacted> + 48
14 libxpc.dylib                   0x24784319 <redacted> + 64
15 libxpc.dylib                   0x2477fbb9 <redacted> + 1512
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x245c75a1 <redacted> + 516
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x245cd9ed <redacted> + 592
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x245c689b <redacted> + 362
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x245cd9ed <redacted> + 592
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x245c6e17 <redacted> + 282
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x245cd9ed <redacted> + 592
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x245c6e17 <redacted> + 282
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x245cf20d <redacted> + 400
24 libdispatch.dylib              0x245cf07b <redacted> + 94
25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x24762e0d _pthread_wqthread + 1024
26 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x247629fc start_wqthread + 8
```

We're using CoreLocation to monitor & range specific beacon regions and here's the code to find nearby beacon. 
Also note that `HPBeaconManager` reinitilizes as App comes to foreground, And from crashlytics reports
It looks like it happens when app comes to foreground. Does destorying CLLocationManger object and reinitilizing can
cause this issue? Any guidence in right direction will be appreciated.

Here's the calling code.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        self.beaconManager = HPBeaconManager()
        self.beaconManager?.startMonitoring()
        return true;
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication)
          if (( self.beaconManager ) != nil){
            self.beaconManager = nil;
        }
        self.beaconManager = HPBeaconManager()
        self.beaconManager?.startRanging()
}
```

Here's the HPBeaconManager implementation.

```
class HPBeaconManager: NSObject , CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var propertyBeaconRegion: HPBeaconRegion?
    var agentBeaconRegion: HPBeaconRegion?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var delegate:BeaconManagerDelegate?
    var beacons:NSMutableSet = NSMutableSet()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.propertyBeaconRegion = HPBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: HPBeaconCommons.propertyUUID, major: CLBeaconMajorValue(1), identifier: HPBeaconCommons.propertyBeaconIdentifier)
        self.agentBeaconRegion = HPBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: HPBeaconCommons.agentUUID, major: CLBeaconMajorValue(1), identifier: HPBeaconCommons.agentBeaconIdentifier)

        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    func startMonitoring() -> Void {

        self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(self.agentBeaconRegion!)
        self.locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(self.propertyBeaconRegion!)

        self.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(self.agentBeaconRegion!)
        self.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(self.propertyBeaconRegion!)

        strongSelf.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func stopMonitoring() -> Void {
        self.locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(self.agentBeaconRegion!)
        self.locationManager.stopMonitoringForRegion(self.propertyBeaconRegion!)

        self.locationManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(self.agentBeaconRegion!)
        self.locationManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(self.propertyBeaconRegion!)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func startRanging() {
        self.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(self.agentBeaconRegion!)
        self.locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(self.propertyBeaconRegion!)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLRegion) {
        NSLog("\n ************** Monitoring starts for region %@", region.identifier)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didDetermineState state: CLRegionState, forRegion region: CLRegion) {

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
        NSLog("\n ************** Did Enter Region")
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {

    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        var locationArray = locations as NSArray
        if  locationArray.count > 0 {
            var locationObj = locationArray.lastObject as! CLLocation
            var coord = locationObj.coordinate
            let loationString = "\(coord.latitude)|\(coord.longitude)"
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {

        if beacons.count > 0 {
            let nearestBeacon:CLBeacon = beacons[0] as! CLBeacon
            ....    
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .AuthorizedAlways {
            NSLog("Location Access (Always) granted!")
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time_t(0.5), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [weak self] in
                if let strongSelf = self {
                    if manager.rangedRegions.isEmpty {
                        NSLog("Ranged region is empty")
                    }
                    strongSelf.startMonitoring()
                }
            })

        } else if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            NSLog("Location Access (When In Use) granted!")
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time_t(0.5), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { [weak self] in
                if let strongSelf = self {
                    if manager.rangedRegions.isEmpty {
                        NSLog("Ranged region is empty")
                    }
                    strongSelf.startMonitoring()
                }
            })
        } else if status == .Denied || status == .Restricted {
            NSLog("Location Access (When In Use) denied!")
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NSLog("BeaconManager cleanup")
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        self.locationManager.delegate = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't answer your question but I suggest you adopt a "Swiftier" syntax for your code. Useless semicolons everywhere, no need to specify "Void" when you return nothing, use of NSLog where a simple print would do the magic.

Comment: Edited.. Thanks for the suggestions.. I'm using NSLogs because when performed on physical device, NSLog statements appear in the device's console whereas println only appears in the debugger console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it's not obvious this would be causing a crash, the way `CLBeaconManager` is started in `applicationDidBecomeActive` could be causing problems.

Whenever the app comes to the foreground, a new `HPBeaconManager` is constructed, a new `CLLocationManager` object is created.  The old `HPBeaconManager` is de-referenced leading ARC to garbage collect it and destroy it at a later time, at which time the `deinit()` method will get called and the first locationManager's delegate is set to nil.  Until that happens, delegate methods will still be called on the old `HPBeaconManager` at the same time the new `HPBeaconManager` is active.

In theory this all should work.  But depending on how long it takes for ARC to clean up the old `HPBeaconManager` and `CLLocationManager` instances, it is possible that a user bringing the app back and forth to the foreground could end up with quite a few active at the same time.  It wouldn't surprise me if this created subtle bugs that could cause crashes in the internals of `CoreLocation`.

I would suggest refactoring `HPBeaconManager` so that you can re-initialize it as needed when the app comes to the foreground without creating a new object instance.  Avoiding this object churn may make the app more stable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer davidgyoung, 

Only reason I'm creating new `CLLocationManger` object when app comes to foreground because I want to restart ranging in foreground. 


From my testing I found `CLLocationManger` restarts ranging when there no `rangedRegions` associated with it, I mean it should be brand new object. Is there anyway we can restart ranging with existing `CLLocationManager` object? so I don't have to create/destroy it again every time when app comes to foreground.

Comment: Is there a specific reason  to **restart** ranging?  Is there any reason you cannot just keep ranging?  If you are unsure it is started you can safely call the start method a second time. And if you really do need to restart for some reason, just call stop then start again with the same `CLLocationManager` object.  I would be  surprised if it made any difference.

Comment: Yes, you're right @davidgyoung. I don't need to restart ranging and therefore there is no need for new `CLLocationManger` object. In fact It was always ranging but there was small bug. I was collecting ranged beacons in a `Set` and it will ignore those beacons which are already in a `Set` or processed, and sadly I removed all log statement while ranging because it was polluting console so I'm not aware of what's going on. The simple fix was when app comes to foreground I just cleared that `Sat`, and all beacons got reprocessed. That fixed my problem. Thanks for pointing me in right direction.